# How to fix `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` error on strapi server?

Tags: npm, strapi

When I try to run commands like `start` or `develop` I get these errors on my local machine and can not start the strapi server. I already did `yarn install` to install dependencies but it's not working. Also tried to run the server with npm and yarn.
[image: error]

Comment: This likely shows that strapi can’t connect to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strapi can't find your Postgres database. You can configure database access through configuration file or by using environment variables.

See [documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/database) for details.